# How to allow the input which is having white space and character limit is 15 using regex

Tags: regex

For one of my projects, I just want to validate the input which has the following criteria:

- Input may have white spaces, but not all spaces
- Input must at least contain one or more characters
- white space is not mandatory
- Input has to allow any keyboard character

For Example :

1. *space14chars*
2. *#$space12chars*
3. *&^11charsspace*

I didn't try much to write the regular expression, as I am a newbie to this.

```
^[\x00-\x7E\s]{0,15}$
```

But the above expression is allowing all spaces, which is limited to 15 chars -  it is not satisfying the first criteria.

Comment: Try `^(?!\s+$)[\x00-\x7E\s]{1,15}$`

Comment: Didn't my comment work, BTW?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for ?

`^(?!\s+$)[\x00-\x7E]{0,14}$`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?!\s+$)[\x00-\x7E]{1,15}$
```

It matches:

The "Input may have white spaces, but not all spaces" condition is met with a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\s+$)` placed immediately after the start-of-string anchor (to only run the check once).

The "Input must at least contain one or more characters" is easily met with a `{1,15}` [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit): the lower bound is set to `1`, so there must be at least 1 char. The upper bound is set to `15`, you may adjust it as per your evolving requirements.

The "white space is not mandatory" condition is met due to the use of a single generic character class that matches other types of chars, too.

The "Input has to allow any keyboard character" condition is already met by your initial expression, as `[\x00-\x7E]` matches an ASCII char range.